# getting email and photo from phone contact not working

Tags: android

I am trying to display name, phone number, image and email from phone contact list. Unfortunately image and email is not retrieving from contact. Contact name and phone number is displaying correctly.

Have a look in my code,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    selectUsers = new ArrayList<SelectUser>();
    resolver = getContentResolver();

    contacts_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);

    phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    LoadContact loadContact = new LoadContact();
    loadContact.execute();  
}

class LoadContact extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // Get Contact list from Phone

        if (phones != null) {
            Log.e("count", "" + phones.getCount());
            if (phones.getCount() == 0) {

            }

            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
                String selected_name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                String EmailAddr = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                String image_thumb = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));

                try {
                    if (image_thumb != null) {
                       bit_thumb = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(resolver, Uri.parse(image_thumb));
                    } else {
                        Log.e("No Image Thumb", "--------------");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                SelectUser selectUser = new SelectUser();
                selectUser.setThumb(bit_thumb);
                selectUser.setName(selected_name);
                selectUser.setPhone(phoneNumber);
                selectUser.setEmail(EmailAddr);
                selectUser.setCheckedBox(false);
                selectUsers.add(selectUser);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("Cursor close 1", "----------------");
        }
        //phones.close();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        adapter = new SelectUserAdapter(selectUsers, MainActivity.this);
        contacts_list.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Select item on listclick
        contacts_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Log.e("search", "here---------------- listener");

                data = selectUsers.get(i);

                String phoneNumber = data.getPhone();
                String email = data.getEmail();
                String name = data.getName();

                Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleContact.class);
                i1.putExtra("name", name);
                i1.putExtra("phone_number", phoneNumber);
                i1.putExtra("email", email);
                startActivity(i1);
            }
        });

        contacts_list.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Whats wrong in my code. Can any one know the issue. Please edit in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following method for gettting email and photo from contact.

```
public ArrayList<String> getEmailAndPhoto(){
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        ContentResolver cur = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cur.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                Cursor cur1 = cur.query( 
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", 
                                new String[]{id}, null); 
                while (cur1.moveToNext()) { 
                    String name=cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    Log.e("Name :", name);
                    String email = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    String photo = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.DATA1));
                    Log.e("Email", email);
                    if(email!=null){
                        names.add(email);
                    }
                   // if(photo!=null){ //for getting photo.
                    //  names.add(photo);
                   // }
                } 
                cur1.close();
            }
        }
        return names;
    }
```

that's it.

Comment: this is extremely **slow** method of accessing the data since you have to run `N`+1 `query` calls, where `N` is number of contacts

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching i got the answer. Anyone having same problem can refer this,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    selectUsers = new ArrayList<SelectUser>();
    resolver = getContentResolver();

    contacts_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);

    phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    LoadContact loadContact = new LoadContact();
    loadContact.execute();  
}

class LoadContact extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // Get Contact list from Phone

        if (phones != null) {
            Log.e("count", "" + phones.getCount());
            if (phones.getCount() == 0) {

            }

            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
                String selected_name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                String EmailAddr = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                String image_thumb = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));

                try {
                    if (image_thumb != null) {
                       bit_thumb = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(resolver, Uri.parse(image_thumb));
                    } else {
                        Log.e("No Image Thumb", "--------------");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                SelectUser selectUser = new SelectUser();
                selectUser.setThumb(bit_thumb);
                selectUser.setName(selected_name);
                selectUser.setPhone(phoneNumber);
                Cursor emailCursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    emails = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    System.out.println("Email : " + emails);
                    selectUser.setEmail(emails);
                }
                emailCursor.close();

                selectUser.setCheckedBox(false);
                selectUsers.add(selectUser);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("Cursor close 1", "----------------");
        }
        //phones.close();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        adapter = new SelectUserAdapter(selectUsers, MainActivity.this);
        contacts_list.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Select item on listclick
        contacts_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Log.e("search", "here---------------- listener");

                data = selectUsers.get(i);

                String phoneNumber = data.getPhone();
                String email = data.getEmail();
                String name = data.getName();

                Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleContact.class);
                i1.putExtra("name", name);
                i1.putExtra("phone_number", phoneNumber);
                i1.putExtra("email", email);
                startActivity(i1);
            }
        });

        contacts_list.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is extremely **slow** method of accessing the data since you have to run `N`+1 `query` calls, where `N` is number of contacts, also it does NOT find the users with no phone number

Comment: please tell me why do you want to use such a slow method of loading contact's data, why?

Comment: @pskink : actually i know only this method.

Comment: i gave you a link yesterday, didn't i?

Comment: and? is there a difference?